# How to read response data from nsIInputStream

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am trying to create a fire-bug like extension for firefox which is actually dev-tool extension. I have registered `httpRequestObserver` to observe `http-on-examine-response` event. I have a listener  with below method implemented.

```
onDataAvailable: function(request, context, inputStream, offset, count) {
    //I get the request URL using request.name
    //What I need to do is fetch response data from inputStream
}
```

I have read the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIInputStream) but still can't figure out.

I am looking for a way to read all the data from `inputStream`.

Let me know in case more details are required.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not a stream expert but this is some ways of doing things. I recommend Method 1 below, if you find problems with that, then go to Method 2, than if still problems, then research Method 3. Method 1 is definitely the most proper, as it follows contratcts agreement.

#### Method 1 - `nsIScriptableScream` `read`

Hold a global buffer and on start request blank it, and on data available populate it.

```
var ScriptableInputStream = CC("@mozilla.org/scriptableinputstream;1", "nsIScriptableInputStream", "init");

var blah = {
    data: '',
    onStartRequest: function (aRequest, aContext) {
        this.data = '';
    },
    onDataAvailable: function(request, context, inputStream, offset, count) {
        var scriptStream = new ScriptableInputStream(inputStream);
        this.data += scriptStream.read(count);
        scriptStream.close();
    }
};
```

#### Method 2 - `nsIBinaryInputStream` `readBytes`

I don't know what advantage this `readBytes` method has, it might be that you can use this method for images as well, and the above method won't read images I'm not sure. This method also holds a global buffer and on start request blank it, and on data available populate it. Another advantage may be that you don't need to `close` a binary input stream, I'm not sure about this point though. I think it has no contract so you can reuse it.

```
var bstream = Cc["@mozilla.org/binaryinputstream;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsIBinaryInputStream);

var blah = {
    data: '',
    onStartRequest: function (aRequest, aContext) {
        this.data = '';
    },
    onDataAvailable: function(request, context, inputStream, offset, count) {
        bstream.setInputStream(inputStream);
        var size = 0;
        while(size = bstream.available()) {
            this.data.value += bstream.readBytes(size);
        }
    }
};
```

#### Method 3 - this is another method i used in tracing listener

This method here I'm just copy pasting, as I don't understand it that well. I use it here though: [GitHub :: Noitidart / demo-nsITraceableChannel #L120](https://github.com/Noitidart/demo-nsITraceableChannel/blob/343983bbae3798bd391d6fc6f59192236e8cd9d4/bootstrap.js#L120)

```
function CCIN(cName, ifaceName) {
    return Cc[cName].createInstance(Ci[ifaceName]);
}

TracingListener.prototype =
{
    onDataAvailable: function(request, context, inputStream, offset, count)
    {
        var binaryInputStream = CCIN("@mozilla.org/binaryinputstream;1",
                "nsIBinaryInputStream");
        var storageStream = CCIN("@mozilla.org/storagestream;1", "nsIStorageStream");
        var binaryOutputStream = CCIN("@mozilla.org/binaryoutputstream;1",
                "nsIBinaryOutputStream");

        binaryInputStream.setInputStream(inputStream);
        storageStream.init(8192, count, null);
        binaryOutputStream.setOutputStream(storageStream.getOutputStream(0));

        // Copy received data as they come.
        var data = binaryInputStream.readBytes(count);
        this.receivedData.push(data);

        binaryOutputStream.writeBytes(data, count);

        this.originalListener.onDataAvailable(request, context, storageStream.newInputStream(0), offset, count);
```

Comment: Thanks @Noitidart. Just looking at the snippets I feel Method 1 would work for scripts but not for images. Method 2 and Method 3 being binary input stream will work for both. Method 3 looks better. I'll try these tomorrow.

Comment: Actually for method 1 I came across this: "Use readBytes to get binary data, read to read a (null-terminated) string". So if read doesn't work, then try `readBytes`, `nsIScirptableInputStream` also has it. Then go to method 2. Method 3 is basically method 2, but also uses storage stream to do i'm not sure what.

Comment: Fine. Even I found a [link](http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/firebug/nsitraceablechannel-intercept-http-traffic/). It says `The listener is realized as a wrapper of the original listener. So, don't forget to call it in each method.` So the last line in Method 3 seems to be important.

Comment: Using the original listener is important if you're copying data __in parallel__ from an existing stream, so ignore that, you aren't doing anything in parallel. Thats like if you want to download the sourcecode to a page thats loading without having to re-fetch that page from either cache or fresh call to url.

Comment: Also in the stuff above I add to a string with `+=`, this I hear is not as effective as `push`'ing to array and then join'ing that array into a string on `onStopRequest`. I'm not sure if this is true, but if you want to do it, then in `onStartRequest` do `this.data = []` and in `onDataAvailable` do `this.data.push(scriptStream.read(count))` and `in `onStopRequest` do `this.data = this.data.join('');` I'm hoping @nmaier can comment on all this junk I spewed, hopefully some of it is true.